# WooCommerce product does not contain images yet when publish_product hook fires

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm writing a plugin for WooCommerce (which is a plugin for Wordpress) that needs to collect data about a product when it is saved. To do this, I am hooking into the `publish_product` action.

```
add_action ('publish_product', 'plugin_xyz_publish_product', 20, 2);

function plugin_xyz_publish_product ($id, $post)
{
    $productFactory = new WC_Product_Factory ();
    $product = $productFactory->get_product ($id);

    $productImageId = $product->get_image_id ();
    $productImage = wp_get_attachment_url ($productImageId);

    $productGalleryImageIds = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids ();
    $productGalleryImages = [];
    foreach ($productGalleryImageIds as $attachmentId)
        $productGalleryImages[] = wp_get_attachment_url ($attachmentId);

    die (var_dump ($product, $productGalleryImageIds, $productGalleryImages, $productImage, get_post_meta ($post->ID)));
}
```

The `var_dump` statement outputs the following; https://hastebin.com/honupuyedu.php

As can be seen, the product image is in there, yet the product gallery images (which are attachments in Wordpress) are not. It seems like attachments are only saved after the *publish* hook is fired. The fact that because of ending the script (`die ()`) at the end of my function the product gallery images are missing on the product page (they are not getting saved to the database) seems to confirm this. When I remove `die ()` the attachments are getting saved fine.
I still cannot access these attachments programatically, however. Any thoughts?

Comment: The images aren't saved until the [`woocommerce_process_product_meta`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/d441e34ef5d1c2201f120fff0f470c8c7e150e2f/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-meta-boxes.php#L62) hook so you should attach to the same hook with a later priority, ie: 30.

Comment: @helgatheviking `add_action ('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'plugin_xyz_process_product_meta', 30, 2);` does the trick :) Thanks. Might want to add this as an answer rather than a comment, though...

Comment: Done. If you wouldn't mind accepting it, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images aren't saved until the `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook (on priority 20) so you should attach to the same hook with a later priority, ie: 30

Additionally, the best way to get the product object is via `wc_get_product()`, so I've adjusted your code for that.

```
add_action ('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'plugin_xyz_process_product_meta', 30, 2);

function plugin_xyz_publish_product ($id, $post)
{
    $product = wc_get_product( $id );

    $productImageId = $product->get_image_id ();
    $productImage = wp_get_attachment_url ($productImageId);

    $productGalleryImageIds = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids ();
    $productGalleryImages = [];
    foreach ($productGalleryImageIds as $attachmentId) {
        $productGalleryImages[] = wp_get_attachment_url ($attachmentId);
    }

    die (var_dump ($product, $productGalleryImageIds, $productGalleryImages, $productImage, get_post_meta ($post->ID)));
}
```